# remove trailiing slash except one

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have following code below ;

```
RewriteRule  ^((?!fr|en).*)\/(\?.*)?$     /$1 [L,R=301]
```

and while i am trying;

```
example.com/fr/ 
example.com/en/
```

turns to

```
example.com/fr/
example.com/en/
```

which is what i want to however once i try to;

```
example.com/frabcdefg/
example.com/enabcedefg/
```

then it doesn't remove the trailing slash that because it begins with en or fr but it should be.

Is there any way to do so ?

edit:
what i want to achieve while i am trying below is;

```
example.com/fr/
```

should nothing changed as below;

```
example.com/fr/
```

however once i try;

```
example.com/frabcde/
```

it should turn to;

```
example.com/frabcde
```

should remove trailing slash at the end of.

Comment: your goal is unclear. please try to explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!(?:fr|en)/).+?)/$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```